# I am having a problem with toggle button. Whenever I click on toggle button, the function doesnot respond and it does not change to cross sign?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a toggle button and I added a function through which when I click on toggle button it should change to cross sign whic I added through Css. But I do not understand it is not working?
My code is here
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Navbar Toggle</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="toggle">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trends</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #333945;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #019031;
  color: white;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar ul a {
  font-size: 5vh;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
}

.navbar ul a:hover {
  background-color: #333945;
}

.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle .bar1, .toggle .bar2, .toggle .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 6px 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
let toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");

toggle.addEventListener("click",myToggle,false);

function myToggle(){
    toggleElement.classList.toggle("change"); 
}
```

**That's all code it is. Please help me in this problem. I am new to Javascript.**

Comment: in the above `toggle` is a nodelist collection so you cannot assign an event listener directly to it - you need to iterate through the collection and assign to each member element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the result returned by `getElementsByClassName` is a nodelist collection you need to access the members of that collection separately in order to assign an event handler. If there were multiple elements on the page matching that `className` the snippet below would assign the `click` event handler to each.

```js
Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName("toggle") ).forEach( bttn=>{
 bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  this.classList.toggle('change')
 });
})
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #333945;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #019031;
  color: white;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar ul a {
  font-size: 5vh;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
}

.navbar ul a:hover {
  background-color: #333945;
}

.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle .bar1, .toggle .bar2, .toggle .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 6px 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="toggle">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trends</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Rather than using `getElementsByClassName` you could access the individual element by using `querySelector` instead: like this:

```
document.querySelector('li.toggle').addEventListener('click',function(e){/*as before*/})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You need to get the first element from the `getElementsByClassName`, like so `let toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0]`. Or, you could also do `let toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle")`
2. You're calling `toggleElement.classList.toggle("change")` but you've named the element `toggle`, so you'll have to change to `toggle.classList.toggle("change")`

Then it should work, see below:

```js
let toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0];

toggle.addEventListener("click", myToggle, false);

function myToggle() {
  toggle.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #333945;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #019031;
  color: white;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar ul a {
  font-size: 5vh;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
}

.navbar ul a:hover {
  background-color: #333945;
}

.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle .bar1,
.toggle .bar2,
.toggle .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 6px 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="toggle">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trends</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```